# Xcode Targets, projects and tests?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

what does exactly the settings for target mean. and how does it differ from project and/or test settings (which makes the project a build-only state).
My doubt is the clarity among all three of these and i need to understand a perpetual scope of all of them.

THanks,.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application have a single build/test settings but it can have multiple targets.

Suppose you are creating an application. Now you are receiving same application with just UI theme changes. In that case no need to create another project but you can create another target in same project. In the same way a project can have multiple targets which produce framework, static library etc.

So, whatever target specific settings you need to make will be made under target settings. Common settings will be part of build settings. If you are putting values in both settings, target settings will get highest priority.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks @Apurv! but need more clarity on this topic for my framework develpoment and was expecting a more low-level segregation of them (with memory, pointers, flags and all aspects) rather than a plain theoretical one.

Comment: You should read this document. It covers all details. [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html)

Comment: Ya sure wil go through it, newayz wanted some experts solution here. np :(